# HTTPS security is compromised by blob in Edge

Tags: javascript, blob, microsoft-edge, web-worker

I'm attempting to create a web worker from a blob:

```
var workerUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["console.log('inside worker')"], {type: "text/javascript"}));
var worker = new Worker(workerUrl);
URL.revokeObjectURL(workerUrl);
```

This code works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but when running it in Edge I get this error in the JavaScript console:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by blob:https://example.com/b6996513-0a45-443b-b163-1fb2a77ac2a8
```

Furthermore, "inside worker" never gets printed.

How can I get this code to work correctly in Edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not entirely aware of the inter workings, this appears to be caused by a race condition where the blob gets revoked before the web worker can be created.

Putting `URL.revokeObjectURL()` inside `setTimeout()` with a sufficient delay fixes the problem:

```
var workerUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(["console.log('inside worker')"], {type: "text/javascript"}));
var worker = new Worker(workerUrl);
setTimeout(function() {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(workerUrl);
}, 500); // you may have to increase the delay here
```

A more advanced solution would involve adding code *inside* the worker to `postMessage()` back to the main page triggering the call to `URL.revokeObjectUrl()`. This would probably be the "correct" way to do it, but the workaround above is significantly simpler.

Comment: great! it works for IE (it fails as described) and EDGE (it fails silently)